# Como concatenar varios objeto del DOM en un ARRAY

Tags: javascript

Lo que busco es: concatenar varios objeto del DOM en dorma de array para realizar una llamada con una sola variable que tenga la direccion de multiples hijos de los tag ejemplo : #menu>ul>li>a => Toda esta llamadas busco almacenarlo en una sola variable.

Nota: el codigo no se ejecuta porque falta un archivo llamado index1.php?variables, NO SE COMO COLOCAR OTRO ARCHIVO

Otro detalle aparte que deseo preguntar es este : Se puede imprimir el codigo de un document.getElementId('tag'); como estring ?

```js
addEventListener('load',evento,false);
// function evento() {
//  var div 
//  div = document.getElementById('menu');
//  var vec = div.getElementsByTagName('li');
//  var a = vec[].getElementsByTagName('a').addEventListener('click'url,false);
 
//  for(i=1; i <=a.length i++){
//   console.log(a[i]);
//  }
function evento() {
 for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  document.getElementById('a'+i).addEventListener('click',url,false);;
 }
}

function url(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var url = e.target.getAttribute('href');
 cargarUrl(url);
}

var conex;
function cargarUrl(url) {
 conex = new XMLHttpRequest();
 conex.onreadystatechange = EstadoServido;
 conex.open('GET',url,true);
 conex.send();
}

function EstadoServido() {
 var caja = document.getElementById('container')
 if (conex.readyState == 4) {
  caja.innerHTML = conex.responseText;
 }else{
  caja.innerHTML = 'Cargando .....'
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Comentarios</title>
  <script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="menu">
    

    
    <li><a href="#">Enlaces creados 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=12-10-2018">Enlaces creados 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=13-10-2018">Enlaces creados 3</a></li>
  </div>
  <div id="container" style="border : 1px solid red;padding: 60px;width: 300px; margin: 20px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo la parte de "concatenar". Que es lo que quieres hacer concretamente.

Comment: Me refiero a llamar todos los DOM #menu li a desde una sola variable

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) para crear una lista estática (no viva) de elementos que cumplan con el selector indicado. Por estática quiere decir que no se actualizará si se añaden nuevos elementos que cumplan con el selector.

En tu código en particular, podría no haber funcionado con `#menu>ul>li>a` porque no tienes un elemento `ul` por lo que el selector no coincidiría con nada.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando (después de añadir el `ul`):

```js
var enlaces = document.querySelectorAll("#menu>ul>li>a");

console.log(enlaces);
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Enlaces creados 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=12-10-2018">Enlaces creados 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=13-10-2018">Enlaces creados 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```